# In the c code below why is second element getting the value of first element of array automatically

Tags: c, arrays

this array is initialized with only one element and only first element is set with a variable but when i call first and second element then both are shown the same (i.e. a)...

i wanted the whole array "temp" but instead of getting output "a", i am getting
"aa" because the second element also has value "a" somehow...

BTW about the Undefined Behaviour...I simply wanted use the array "temp" as a string(which explains the %s) and get only one value to use...but i was always getting two (i.e. aa) so it was then i thought of looping through the loop to see why was it happening and i saw that the second element was also holding value...

```
int main(void)
{
    char c = 'a';
    char temp[1];
    temp[0] = c;
    printf("the whole array is:%s", temp);
    printf("the first element is %c and second is %c\n",temp[0],temp[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

expected result was `a`.
actual result was `aa`.

Didn't expected second element without initializing or setting it

Comment: `temp[1]` accesses out of bounds! Your array only has a single element

Comment: If you don't initialize a variable, its value is unspecified. It's allowed to be *absolutely anything* (and to change based on your compiler version / system architecture / time-of-day / etc).

Comment: Undefined behavior is undefined.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Well, in this case you cannot initialize `temp[1]` because it doesn't exist.

Comment: A relevant [meta] link: [Should I try to explain undefined behavior?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271372/should-i-try-to-explain-undefined-behaviour) -- consensus is "maybe, but first and foremost, make it clear that that the behavior in question *must not be relied on*".

Comment: Can you explain why you thought `%s` was the right format specifier to output a single character? (Or why you thought `temp` contained a string?) That would help those answering to clear up the precise misconception you have.

Comment: @David Schwartz Actually i am taking Harvabrd's CS50 course in which they have their own online IDE and their own library which include's string data type which is not inherently present in C(correct me if i am wrong).

Comment: @David Schwartz Please read the edited question for clarity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two issues here:

1. A string in C is an array of characters **terminated by a null character**. Since your array is only allocated to have one character, there is no space for a null terminator.
2. The array `char temp[1];` only holds a single character. So in your `printf()` statement, `temp[0]` is legal, but `temp[1]` is not.

Both of these situations cause so-called "undefined behavior". This means that just about anything can happen because the results are not defined by the C standard.

Comment: @Rashim_narayan The edit doesn't change my answer. `%s` expects a NULL terminated string. Since you don't have one, you encounter UB.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is an UB (Undefined Behavior). You have only one element in your array, but you access two. You also `printf` the string - and the `printf` function is accessing the array outside of its bounds. So any output is possible.

Change the code by adding the second element for the terminating zero

```
char c = 'a';
char temp[2];
temp[1] = 0;
temp[0] = c;
printf("the whole array is:%s", temp);
printf("the first element is %c and second is %c\n",temp[0],temp[1]);
return 0;
```

Comment: What does this add to the answer preceding it by two minutes?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy when you write the answer you do not see other. BTW in that answer UB is not mentioned at all, and it does not explain the output - which is unpredictable